# How to solve sub-directory issue on hosting server

Tags: .htaccess

I hosted a website to a sub-directory in a hosting server.
But it is redirected to the main domain when I try to navigate to the sub-url of the website.
So, I added the .htaccess file to solve this problem.
The .htaccess file is the following.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

But I am getting the problem continuously.
Please let me know how I can solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the following contents to your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-directory/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub-directory/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```